# How do I connect to my phone that's in vigilant coma?

Tags: internal-storage, nexus-4, connection-issues, water-damage

So I have this phone that looks like it's working fine under the hood, but input (power button and touchscreen) as well as the output (display) are pretty much dead.

> **Interlude on what happened**
>
> 1. Clumsy me dropped his phone in water.
> 2. Turning it off immediately and heating it through to dry gave red
>      light. (battery cannot be removed quickly)
> 3. Volume down + power for 60 seconds caused life signs to reappear.
> 4. After recharge and start, display was very washed out (very white, barely readable) and touchscreen was partially unresponsive. Besides that the phone worked normally.
> 5. Display "faded" further over couple of hours. Now being black, flickering when plugged to power (nothings visible, just black
>      flickering). Volume buttons occasionally still work, providing sound
>      feedback for changing the volume.

I got a new phone (see, I like to fix things, but with water damage you never know what got damaged. I keep the phone and see if I can fix it later, but for now I use a new one, because I need to call people 'n stuff, ok?)

**How can I access the data on the phone?**
I installed adb, but in order to connect to the phone, the phone has to be enabled for that. I don't remember if I ever changed that setting, but connecting it to the pc and listing all the connected devices gave nothing. I assume that it is not set up for that.

I read about a safe mode, but that needs a phone that's turned off and a power button. My phone is on and the power button doesn't work. At least I *think* it doesn't work.

**Is there any way to access the phone via cable from outside to bypass the broken io?** Or is my only option to actually fix the phone to make a regular connection to it?